# Debug Adobe AIR iOS app downloaded from TestFlight

Tags: air, adobe

I would like to view trace statements from my AIR iOS app that has been packaged for production using an AppStore provisioning profile and downloaded from TestFlight.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get the console.log or traces from a testflight app cause it is already distributed. You can only have access to those while testing / debugging. You can use a log system (like Firebase analytics for example) to check those traces.

Some more information about how to access logs in general, can be found [here.](https://airnativeextensions.github.io/tutorials/device-logs)